# How to hide the status bar in WP7 (Silverlight)

Tags: windows-phone-7, fullscreen, statusbar

I'm trying to hide the statur bar on the top of my Silverlight Windows Phone 7 app.
I found this while searching stackoverflow, but is for Xna.

```
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this); 
graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
```

I tried it in my app but it does not work.
I know it is possible because the board express and xda apps have the feature to hide/show the statusbar.

Comment: You should add the result in an answer, rather than modifying the question.

Comment: @Twenty40 Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq to see why I've edited your question and http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for assistance when posting future questions

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new in all this. I keep that in mind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SystemTray.IsVisible = false;
}
```

Comment: In Xaml page  shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False" can use

Answer (score 5):

I think Mahantesh's answer should be the accepted one for WP8:

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```

Put that in the XAML as it the property already defined there (set to true by default).

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative:**

```
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs events)
{
  SystemTray.IsVisible = false;
}
```